# Wattage of DC device is not equal to AC

Tags: led, led-driver, ohms-law, watts

I have a led driver (LPC-20-700) that is 30V and 700mA, which makes it 21W.

I run 10 leds (≈ 2.8V drop) in series with it and it is an constant current device. If I plug my multimeter between, I do get the reading of 700mA.

When I use a [little device](http://img.auctiva.com/imgdata/1/4/6/7/2/7/7/webimg/657683491_o.jpg) (AC power consumption meter?) that checks the power consumption of devices I plug into DC, the reading tells me it's only 5.6W.

I can't wrap my head around what I'm missing here. Why are the numbers not equal?

Comment: What "little device that checks the power consumption" are you using?

Comment: How are the LEDs connected? How is the LED driver connected? Please show a schematic.

Comment: @RonBeyer I edited my question and added more information.

Comment: @vofa The leds are just in series and the driver powers them.

Comment: Are the LEDs all lighting up?

Comment: @Finbarr Yes, but they are not bright as expected. I will add a picture.

Comment: "(AC power consumption meter?) that checks the power consumption of devices I plug into DC" makes absolutely no sense. If you're measuring DC power with it, don't expect it to work at all. If you're measuring AC, don't expect it to be very accurate at only a few watts.

Comment: It would help to post the specification of your LEDs too, ideally with a data sheet.

Comment: Have you verified that the AC outlet meter measures correctly when used with other devices?

Comment: The accuracy of said "little AC consumption meter" is probably horrendous at that low power. Anyway, what's your end goal you wish to achieve?

Comment: You seem to be confused, or creating a problem that does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a constant current driver that regulates its output voltage in order to generate the specified current.

30V is the maximum that your driver can output in order to drive 700mA through the LEDs. In practice, it will usually output a lower voltage depending on what sort of LEDs you have connected.

However, 5.6W would suggest an output voltage of just 8V, which is well short of what you'd expect to see across ten LEDs wired in series, so I suspect that either your device is not measuring what you think it is or your LEDs are not wired in series.

Use your multimeter to measure the output voltage across the LEDs and see what you get. Assuming you are still getting 700mA through the LEDs the actual power will be 0.7 times the actual voltage.

Comment: Thank for taking time, I'm a real dumbass and connected them in parallel. I even don't know why or how I didn't notice it. If it makes any better, your answer made me realize. Mods please delete, close this question of ban me.